# Python urllib.urlretrive cannot download image to the folder

Tags: python, selenium, instagram, urllib

I wan to make a instagram photo downloader using python , i will file all the image url for me and then download it to the folder that i specified .

I manage to create a folder also getting the url , but the image doesnt seem to be like downloading to the folder.

Below is the code

```
   def download_image(self, src, image_filename, folder):
        """
        Creates a folder named after a user to to store the image, then downloads the image to the folder.
        """

        folder_path = 'C:/{}'.format(folder)
        #folder_path = 'C:\\.{}'.format(folder)

        if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
            os.mkdir(folder_path)
            print("folder not create")

        img_filename = 'image_{}.jpg'.format(image_filename)
        print(str(src),"  File Name",str(image_filename)," Folder ",str(folder))
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, '{}/{}'.format(folder, img_filename))
```

The output is this

```
# image url
https://instagram.fkul8-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/c120.0.720.720a/s640x640/19534375_479423379059793_7995041966070956032_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fkul8-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=109&oh=7c8e2f8816f17627424bf38d0267f39b&oe=5E7DFCA1   

# file name is the image name and folder name is kwting3
File Name kwt1  Folder  kwting3
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the download file path in your driver initialization? This is usually the accepted method for downloading files to a specific folder.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:/Downloads") # specify some other file path here

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

You will add this code at the very beginning, where your `WebDriver` object gets initialized.

Comment: I tried to set it , but it still wont effect the output

Comment: Are you still using `urllib.request.urlretrieve` ? You don't need this. Setting download directory makes it so you just click the link to download, and that's all. So most of the logic in `download_image()` does not need to be used.